# nhibernate Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
return NHibernateSession.CreateQuery(@"TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Exceptions").ExecuteUpdate();
```

> Exception of type
>   'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException'
>   was thrown. [TRUNCATE TABLE
>   Exceptions] Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException:
>   Exception of type
>   'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException'
>   was thrown. [TRUNCATE TABLE
>   Exceptions]
>
> Source Error:

any idea why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TRUNCATE TABLE is not a valid HQL statement.

Use `CreateSQLQuery` instead of `CreateQuery` to execute SQL statements.

Comment: Off topic: Why does NHibernate expose an ANTLR exception? How is the user supposed to handle that? Shouldn't it should throw an InvalidQuerySyntaxException or whatnot?

Comment: If you look closely, the NoViableAltException is wrapped in a QuerySyntaxException.

Comment: This was simple and amazingly helpful.