# Nhibernate GroupBy multiple and Count

Tags: nhibernate, count, group-by, hql, linq-to-nhibernate

First off I know GroubBy multiple properties has not been implemented yet.

What I want to do is

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM ( 
    SELECT this_.SubmissionDate as y0_
    FROM   [Coupon] this_
    WHERE  this_.PaymentOrder_id is null 
    GROUP BY this_.SubmissionDate,
           this_.Deal_id
) AS query
```

the best I have in Nhibernate is

```
Session.QueryOver<Coupon>().Select(Projections.Group<Coupon>(e => e.SubmissionDate),Projections.Group<Coupon>(e => e.Deal.Id)).Future<object[]>().Count()
```

which brings the whole set and then counts it.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351683/how-can-i-do-this-query-with-nhibernate/4351837#4351837) and created this

```
var count = Session.CreateQuery("select count(*) from (select c.SubmissionDate from Coupon c where c.PaymentOrder.Id is null group by c.SubmissionDate, c.Deal.Id) as query").FutureValue<Int32>();
```

which doesn't work. Throws a

```
Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 21

Exception Details: NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 21
```

more exception

```
[QuerySyntaxException: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 21]
   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException() +118
   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine.Parse() +416
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: The Antlr exception seems to be due to incorrect HQL syntax.
see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799087/nhibernate-antlr-runtime-noviablealtexception.
Is the exception wrapped by an QuerySyntaxException like in the link above?

Comment: i am pretty sure is is the subselect to blame! but I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this, that will do the counting in memory ?

```
var count = Session.CreateQuery("select c.SubmissionDate from Coupon c where c.PaymentOrder.Id is null group by c.SubmissionDate, c.Deal.Id").ToList().Count;
```

HQL doesn't seem to support subqueries outside select and where : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

Otherwise, you could create a stored procedure, and add it in your mapping : [Correct NHibernate Mapping For Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512272/correct-nhibernate-mapping-for-stored-procedure)

Comment: wouldn't this return the whole set of results and count them in memory?